# Preserve SASS indents when copying and pasting with PHPStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm

Is there a way to preserve indentation when copying and pasting SASS in PHPStorm?
I've tried every setting in Preferences > Editor > Smart Keys > Reformat on paste, as suggested all over the internet, but it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: You do not have to try "every" -- just one of them: "None". **P.S.** Do you have Editor Config plugin installed?

Comment: Yes, I tried "None" but it didn't work. I installed the Laravel plugin, but otherwise I'm using the defaults that were setup when I installed the program.